# C++ specialization of subclass iterators by their container type?

Tags: c++, templates, iterator, std, specialization

I'm trying to provide a base class interface (see: Accessor) that provides iterators to all derived class types, but use template specialization of the iterators, instead of run-time polymorphism (ie derived iterators with virtual functions) to optimize those iterators for the container class they iterate.  (The iterators will be used quite often, and I want them to be as fast as possible.)

Aside: I don't need the iterators to be std library compliant, specifically because the items being iterated can't be pointed at directly (operator*, operator->, operator[]) as they are sometimes returned by the Object class through a function call.

Is this possible, or am I stuck with the overhead of using derived iterator classes, and virtual iterator operators on the derived classes?

Currently I'm running into a problem in declaring the base class interface, because I don't know how to allow for the type I'm specializing on to change, yet still write the base class 'iterator' typedef.

```
// base iterator template definition
template <class AccessorType,class ObjType>
class MyTypeIterator
:public std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag,ObjType,ptrdiff_t,ObjType*,ObjType&>
{
  // this class should never be instantiated, only specialized flavors
};

// iterator template definition, specialized for ScalarAccessor
template <class AccessorType,class ObjType>
class MyTypeIterator<ScalarAccessor,Obj>
:public std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag,ObjType,ptrdiff_t,ObjType*,ObjType&>
{
  // implements iterator interface using special knowledge of ScalarAccessor 
};

// iterator template definition, specialized for ObjContainerAccessor
template <class AccessorType,class ObjType>
class MyTypeIterator<ObjContainerAccessor,Obj>
  : public std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag,ObjType,ptrdiff_t,ObjType*,ObjType&>
{
  // implements std::iterator interface using special 
  // knowledge of ObjContainerAccessor 
};

class Obj { ... };                       // my object class
class ObjContainer: public Obj { ... };  // an object that holds other objects

class Accessor
{
 typedef MyTypeIterator<MyBase,Obj>::iterator;

 virtual iterator begin( Obj *objPtr ) = 0;
 virtual iterator end  ( Obj *objPtr ) = 0;

 virtual const char *niceName() const = 0; // other interface fns
};

// a helper class implementing an interface into the Obj class
ScalarAccessor: public Accessor
{
 Accessor::iterator begin( *objPtr ) override
 {
   // I'd like to return how do return an instance of the specialized template 
   // MyTypeIterator<ScalarAccessor,Obj> here, but the following conflicts
   // with the return type of Accessor::iterator.

   // WON'T COMPILE   
   MyTypeIterator<ScalarAccessor,Obj> it( objPtr ); return it; 
 }
 Accessor::iterator end( *objPtr ) override
 { /* same issue as in begin() */ }

 virtual const char *niceName() const { return "Scalar";}

};


// a helper class implementing an interface into the ObjContainer class
ObjContainerAccessor: public Accessor
{
 Accessor::iterator begin( *objPtr ) override
 {
   // I'd like to return how do return an instance of the specialized template 
   // MyTypeIterator<ObjContainerAccessor,Obj> here, but the following conflicts
   // with the return type of Accessor::iterator.

   // WON'T COMPILE   
   MyTypeIterator<ObjContainerAccessor,Obj> it( objPtr ); return it; 
 }
 Accessor::iterator end( *objPtr ) override
 { /* same issue as in begin() */ }

 virtual const char *niceName() const { return "Container";}

};
```

Comment: Your design has a flaw - you are mixing templates with virtual functions

Comment: I disagree.  Can you explain why this is a flawed approach?  I am attempting to implement the iterators with templates, but virtual functions are used separately by the Accessor hierarchy to return the correct iterator for the Accessor class.